# Pyspark From kafkaDirectStream to Postgresql

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i'm trying to insert data from kafka stream using pyspark

my code as below

```
    cols = ['id','name']
    topic = "testing_topic"
    # spark context init
    para_seconds = 10
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSparkStreamingKafka_Testing_01")
    sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, para_seconds)
    # receiver in kafka
    brokers = 'localhost:9092'
    topic = "testing_topic"
    # get streaming data from kafka
    kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic],{'bootstrap.servers':brokers})
    lines = kafkaStream.map(lambda x: json.loads(x[1])).pprint()
```

given the data

> { "id": { "testing": "20210623190332610" }, "name": { "testing": "testname" } }

i tried to use this code

```
x = lines.take(1)
```

to take the data given to sparkContext but it returns error.

is there any guide to transform the data income to string type of dataframe directly? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would start reading first the spark documentation here
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html and it has very detailed example for most of the stuff you are doing.

Moreover, see if the below code is of any help.

```
    from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType, StructType, StructField
    import json
    from pyspark.sql.functions as F
    #{ "id": { "testing": "20210623190332610" }, "name": { "testing": "testname" } }
    data_spark_schema = StructType([
            StructField("id",StructType([
            StructField("testing", StringType(), True),
            StructField("name",StructType([
            StructField("testing", StringType(), True)]),True]),True])

    streaming_df = (
            spark.readStream
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.group.id", "GROUP_ID")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "BOOTSTRAP")
                .option("subscribe", "TOPIC")
                .load()
        ).selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as event_value").select(F.from_json("event_value",data_spark_schema).alias("value"))
    print(streaming_df.schema)

    def write_to_postgres(df, epoch_id):
        mode="append"
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://url:5432/database"
        properties = {"user": "user", "password": "password", "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"}
        df.write.jdbc(url=url, table="schema.table_name", mode=mode, properties=properties)

    streaming_df.writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(write_to_postgres) \
    .option("checkpointLocation", '/checkpoint_path') \
    .outputMode('update') \
    .start()
```

Comment: Hi Akhil, Thanks for answering my question. i tried it and it returns error. so i tried to modified my code to using rdd.foreach()

but currently it's still returns error.